# Paramiko: Why is reading so slow?

Tags: python-3.x, paramiko

Why does this script

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.connect('remote.machine')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('cat 200mb.file')
stdin.close()
while not stdout.channel.exit_status_ready():
    while stdout.channel.recv_ready():
    #if stdout.channel.recv_ready():
        buf = stdout.channel.recv(4096)
```

needs a few minutes while

```
# ssh remote.machine 'cat 200mb.file' > 200mb.file
```

needs less than two seconds? (Yes I know that I will loose some output at the end due to paramikos SSH-behaviour.)

Any suggestions or recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: What part of the code takes so long?

Comment: The whole script. It just reads file output of the remote 'cat 200mb.file', which is 200MB big and I wonder why this takes minutes instead of seconds.

Comment: It may be because you're transferring it in 4KiB blocks, so you'll have to read from the socket many times, and that's expensive. You can try reading 1MiB in one go and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: No, also a 'buf = stdout.channel.recv(409600000000)' does not make any real difference.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone is interested in the answer...
This way I am able to read the data almost in native speed (but can be optimized more):

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.connect('remote.machine')
channel = ssh.get_transport().open_channel('session')
channel.exec_command('cat 200mb.file')

while True:
    (rlist, wlist, xlist) = select.select([channel], [], [], 1)
    if rlist:
        got_data = False
        if channel.recv_ready():
            data = channel.recv(4096)
            if data:
                got_data = True
                #sys.stdout.buffer.write(data)
        if channel.recv_stderr_ready():
            data = channel.recv_stderr(4096)
            if data:
                got_data = True
                #sys.stderr.buffer.write(data)
        if not got_data:
            break

# yes I saw situations where 'channel.exit_status_ready' is NOT ready here!
# (e.g. 'cat non-existent-file': in this case the stderr is small and
# sometimes being read so fast that 'channel.exit_status_ready' returns
# 'False' at first call!
while not channel.exit_status_ready():
    time.sleep(0.1)

#sys.stdout.write("exit code: '%s'\n" % channel.recv_exit_status())
```